# Statistical/ML models when observations have different amounts of input

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, predictive-models, prediction

Let's say we're predicting an employee's performance review score for the following year based on his/her performance review scores from each previous year of their employment.  We might have these training observations (values listed from most recent year to n years ago):

```
Joe (has been with the company 9 years): 94, 97, 81, 79, 84, 89, 92, 91, 88
Jay (has been with the company 3 years): 86, 84, 86
Zoe (has been with the company 1 year ): 92
```

These types of problems come up all the time, and I've never seen a statistical or machine learning model that allows for different amounts of input like this.  I suppose I could create one model for employees who've been there 1 year, another model for employees who've been there 2 years, etc.  But with some employees having 40 years of service the available data can get thin pretty quick.

What is this type of problem called, and what are some of the best models to use in this situation?

Comment: easiest solution is to treat shorter time series as left censored. Bayesian methods would work well...

Comment: Your data looks like a time series with missing or 'censored' data. Depending on what you're trying to predict, different models may be more useful. Predicting anything from one data point ('Zoe') is going to be hard though :)